# Setting cursor to the right on an EditText with HINT Gravity to center

Tags: android, cursor, android-edittext, gravity

Is this possible? Any EditText attribute to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="center"
```

in your xml when you declare the EditText

The first line is to move cursor to the right and the second one to move the hint to the center.
An example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/your_hint_id"
/>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. This is my EditText code:   <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/register_name_hint"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

Comment: I haven't tested the two options together. Try to use first one and the other. For the hint I'm sure that android:gravity="center" works. Probably they don't work together...

Answer (score 1):

This should be the better solution and it worked for me.

```
<EditText 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="1234" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:id="@+id/editText1" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal"></EditText>
```