# how to put Cursor to the right of hint when EditText Gravity set right

Tags: android

here is my layout code:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/trade_num_et"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
     android:hint="@string/input_num"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:background="@color/transparent"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
      android:textSize="@dimen/font_52" >
</EditText>
```

So how can I put set the cursor to the right of the HintText？Thank you~

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting cursor to the right on an EditText with HINT Gravity to center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694800/setting-cursor-to-the-right-on-an-edittext-with-hint-gravity-to-center)

Comment: I don't think that this can be done but check out this accepted answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562959/how-to-set-the-cursor-to-the-right-edittext

Comment: @Duggu I dont think they are the same situation.

Comment: @Mukesh Rana I have checked that before,but it cannot work..

Comment: So I don't think this can be possible.. :( @Darcy

Answer (score 0):

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/search_user"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />
```